# unable to read from Kafka

Tags: spring, docker, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am a beginner with kafka. I am using the docker image Landoop ... I used the console-producer and the console-consumer and I was abale to read/write in the topic
Now I am trying to do the same with spring. I was able to create a new topic, send messages, but I am not able to read them.
These are my java classes:
This is the config class:

```
    @EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

and this is the consumer

```
public class ConsumerService {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "user.subscription", group = "group_id")
    public void consume(String message) {
        System.out.println("Consumed message: " + message);
    }

}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Where did you run the console Kafka tools? Outside or inside of Kafka?

Comment: Try setting `ConsumerConfi.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG=earliest`.

Comment: I used the bash command of landoop "docker run --rm -it --net=host landoop/fast-data-dev bash" and it worked, but when I run my 2 spring boot services, to consume/produce ... I am able to produce and I see it on the Landoop UI, but the other service is not able to consume ...

Comment: Can.you please include your Docker commands in the question?